# property of a separable metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

I think it is a rather easy question but I don't manage to prove it.

If $X$ is a separable metric space, then their exists a dense set $x_m, m \in \mathbb{N}$ in X. What I need to prove is the following: $\forall \delta > 0: X \subset \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} B(x_m, \delta)$. I think the most straightforward proof is using contradiction. So if there exists a $\delta$ such that their exist a point $x \in X$ such that there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in B(x_n, \delta)$. But i don't get any further .

Who Can help me?

Comment: Suppose you have such an $x$ and such a $\delta$. Consider the open set $B(x,\delta)$, what can you say about it.

Comment: then there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in B(x,\delta)$ but what can you do now?

Comment: Since you assumed there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in B(x_{n},\delta)$ this results in a contradiction. To see this, note that $x \in B(x_{n},\delta)$ iff $x_{n} \in B(x,\delta) $.

Comment: ok thanks for the help